# Disabling any HTML put inside textarea and input

Tags: php, html, textarea

I have a textarea which then posts to a database (using PHP and MySQL) but I'd like to be able to disable any HTML, JS etc that's put inside the textarea. The main purpose is to stop people posting URLs etc. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For php you can use [htmlentities](https://www.php.net/htmlentities) to convert the tag from:

```
<style>
```

to

```
&lt;style&gt;
```

Which the browser will not see as tags and will not execute javascript.

Answer (score 1):

To completely stop it, the best thing you could do is `strip_tags($input)`

This will remove any html formatting from your input

[PHP Docs](https://www.php.net/strip_tags)

Answer (score 0):

you can use a php function on server side to encode the text area input. the function to use is [htmlentities()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)